# Wordpress Customise

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, links, optimization

I'm looking for a plugin that lets me put a "please wait" message (similar to **notebook-driver.com** where you're redirected to download link after a few seconds) when people click on certain links.

For example, when people want to download something off my blog, I redirect them to a page with advertisements that is displayed for 5 seconds before the download is initiated.

Does such a plugin exist? or how to do this manually ?
Thanks.....

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are not in scope here. If you are looking to develop this show what you have already tried and ask which specific issues you are having.

Comment: Hello Dear, I have wordpress site http://www.filefobia.com . I am provided laptop and desktop drivers to download. All of download links goes to external servers. So i want to create when user click on any download link, the download page should open with adsense advertisement and 5 to 10 second waiting time before download starts. for your knowledge referral site is www.notebook-driver.com. Please help me madam. I really need it. sorry for my weak english. Please reply. Thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interstitial page on that website isn't part of Wordpress. It's just an external page with some ads and a download link on it.

You can easily do this by yourself. Create a php file named download.php on your server and add the following code to it:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?php $_GET['url'];?>" /></head>
</head>
```

When you link to this page for the download link to work, do it like this: http://yousite.com/download.php?url=http://thedownloadurl.com/app.exe

You can add whatever else you want to download.php, of course.

Comment: Hello alex thanks for answer but, Im newbie to wordpress so can you upload video tutorial on youtube? And second, I have approximately 70000 to 80000 external download links on my wordpress site. So after creating download.php page, can all download links automatically pass with this page with 5-10 second waiting time? please reply me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance..